# Is the empty set a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, relations

Is the empty set is a relation?

In Enderton's book *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*, a relation is defined as a set of ordered pairs. If the empty set is a relation, why is that? In the text, there is an example of a function $\varnothing \to A$. This function is of course is the empty set, so it seems that the empty set is a relation. But I don't see the reason for this.

Comment: Yes: **every** subset of $A\times B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: It is a vacuous relation.

Comment: @copper.hat No need for name calling!

Comment: @Brian M.Scott ,How is it vacuous? Why is true that any subset of $A /times B$ is a relation? In particular for the empty subset?

Comment: @Element: It’s true by definition. The definition of *R is a relation from A to B* is that $R\subseteq A\times B$. (It’s the **empty** relation; I would not call it a vacuous relation.)

Comment: Not only is it a relation but in fact a *function*...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The OP is using a definition of "relation" rather than of "relation from $A$ to $B$"

Comment: @Trevor: How so? A set of ordered pairs is clearly a subset of some $A\times B$ and vice versa.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sure, it's clear to us, but possibly the OP is confused about something very basic, so I thought the distinction might matter.

Comment: @Brian , in my definition it's true that every relation is a subset of a cartesion product of two sets but the invrrsr is not clearly trur.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: It is that time of year in the USA :-).

Comment: @Element $A \times B$ is a set of ordered pairs, so every subset of it is also a set of ordered pairs.  Now use the definition of "relation" as "set of ordered pairs".

Comment: @Element: The inverse is immediate: every subset of $A\times B$ is a set of ordered pairs. This includes the empty set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All the elements of the empty set are ordered pairs. To contradict this statement you will have to provide an element which is a counterexample, an element of the empty set which is not an ordered pair.

Since there is no such element, it follows that all the elements of the empty set are ordered pairs. Therefore the empty set is a relation.

Comment: Hello. I got confused with your answer, suppose we have a formula p in the first order language, why is it true that if we can't prove notp ( that is, if we say notp is not provable ) , that means p is true ?  Why is      (not p is not provable) -> p   a tautology ?

Comment: I'm not sure which answer you're talking about?

Comment: Let's get the statement = "All the elements of the empty sets are ordered pairs" we can translate it to a wff of a first oder language, lets call this formula p.  Then, you are saying that if we can't contradict p  ( provide a counter-example, an element of the empty set which is not an ordered pair ) then p is true ( all the elements of the empty set are ordered pairs ). And by saying that p is true you concluded that the empty set is a relation.So, you are saying that if we can't  prove  notp,  then that means p is true. I would like to understand it in the light of first oder logic.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. Statements of the form "For all $x$ bla bla bla" are true (in a particular structure) if and only if for every $x$ (in that particular structure) it is true that bla bla bla. Consider the empty set as a structure and some predicate whose interpretation is the elements of the universe which are ordered pairs. By the definition of truth, $\forall x\varphi$ is true in the structure if and only if $\exists x\lnot\varphi$ is false in the structure. In the structure whose universe is $\varnothing$ the latter is false because $\exists x(x\in\varnothing)$ is false.

Comment: Really appreciated the clarification, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. This is, by the way, the reason why it's often in logic that we consider only structures with a non-empty universe.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you stated "empty set*s*" however it is "The empty set" becasue there is only one set which is empty. Isn't so?

Comment: @Sufyan: It's called a "typo". :-)

Comment: Of course, I know. How can you be so foolish? At last, you are a future set theorist. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Every element of the empty set is an ordered pair (vacuously), so the empty set is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: The empty set is also a set of ordered triples, _etc._, so one could even say that it is an $n$-ary relation for every $n$.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably best to say that a relation is an ordered triple $(A, B, R)$, where $R \subset A \times B$, so that the two sets on which the relation "operates" are explicit. With that convention, you can say that for any two sets $A$ and $B$, the triple
$$
(A, B, \emptyset)
$$
is a relation on $A$ and $B$.

The downside of using an ordered triple is that you then have to be careful about subsequent definitions where you might only want the "rule" part ($R$) of the relation...but that's not a big deal.

Comment: Perhaps it is the "best" definition but I feel the need to point out that this definition is different from the one the OP is using.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the binary relation $R\subset A\times B$

Then $R=\emptyset  \iff \forall x\in A: \forall y\in B: \neg x R y$

Likewise, $R=A\times B \iff \forall x\in A: \forall y\in B: x R y$

This works even if $A\times B=\emptyset$ (vacuously).