# Question about the definition of the composition of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I am slightly confused about following definition:

> Suppose R is a relation from A to B and S is a relation from B to C.
>   Then the composition of S and R is the relation S ◦ R from A to C
>   defined as follows:
>   $$S \circ R = \{(a,c) \in A \times C \mid \exists b \in B((a,b) \in R  
> \text{ and } (b,c) \in S\}$$

I struggle to explain my question in words, hence I will give you an example to show where I'm confused.

**Case 1**

Suppose

$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, $C = \{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$

$R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$, and $D$ is a relation from $B$ to $C$

$R = \{(a_1,b_1)\}$ and $D = \{(b_1,c_3)\}$

I'm pretty sure that in this case, $R \circ D = \{(a_1,c_3)\}$

But now consider slightly different example:

**Case 2**

$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, $C = \{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$

$R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$, and $D$ is a relation from $B$ to $C$

$R = \{(a_1,b_2)\}$ and $D = \{(b_1,c_3)\}$ (Note that each subsets of $R$ and $D$ now have $b$'s with different indices)

In this case, is $R \circ D = \{(a_1,c_3)\}$ or $R \circ D = \emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your definition is understand by *right to left*:

First you take $(a, \color{red}b) \in R$ and if $( \color{red}b,c) \in S$, then add $(a,c)$ to $S \circ R$

So your computation in case 1 is wrong!, since $(\color{red}{c_3}, ?) \notin R $

For case 2, it is empty!

---

Note that a relation from $A$ to $C$ is *any subset of $A \times C$*, so empty set is also a relation. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583716/is-the-empty-set-a-relation)

Comment: Will I be correct to say that $S \circ R ≠ R \circ S$? Suppose $S \circ R = \{(a,c) \in A \times C \mid \exists b \in B((a,b) \in R  
\text{ and } (b,c) \in S\}$, then $R \circ S =  \{(c,a) \in C \times A \mid \exists b \in B((a,b) \in R  
\text{ and } (b,c) \in S\}$  Is it right?

Comment: In general composition of relation is not commutative!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

The composite relation is not always non-empty.

You have to have the range of $D$ to be a subset of the domain of $ R$ in order for  $RoD$ to be non-empty.

Comment: Yes the empty relation is allowed. I meant in odrer to have a nonempty relation you have to have certain conditions.

Comment: oh sorry! for the first time, I did not see the *not* in your second line!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR No problem